# 2 paginations on one page - Backbone Routes

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I need to handle 2 separate paginations on one page.

At the moment I have only one pagination, the anchors contain just plain hashtags which are parsed by the Route Object like so

**HTML**

```
<a href="#1"></a>
```

**Backbone Router**

```
routes: {
        ":number": "paginate"
    }
```

How would I handle two paginations at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was I wrote a function that parses hash query strings and triggers an event via an aggregator which then gets picked up by whoever needs to react to pagination. In my case it's a collection that clears its' items and adds the next page...

Here's the router in case it helps:

```
define(
    function(){

    var r_Paginate = Backbone.Router.extend({

    /* Initialise Object */
        initialize: function(options){
            Backbone.history.start();
        },
    /* Events */
        routes: {
            ":any" : "query",
        },

    /* Object Methods */
        query: function(a){
            if(a.indexOf('&') > -1){
                var queries = a.split('&');
                for (x in queries){
                    var query = queries[x].split('=');
                    Z.events.trigger('paginate:' + query[0], {'page' : query[1]});
                }
            }
        }

    });
    return r_Paginate
});
```